# Selecting TabItem from code-behind when tabs use a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I've got a TabControl in my WPF application.  The TabControl's ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollction of view objects.  It uses a DataTemplate to populate the visual tree for the tabs from the Items in the collection.

I need to be select the current tabs in the conde-behind in response to actions the user takes on another screen in the application.  When I iterate over the items in the TabControl's Items collection, I get the instances of my view models.

How do I access the actual TabItems and iterate over them, then select the one I want?

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a MVVM approach you should bind your TabControl's SelectedItem property to the same object that holds your ObservableCollection of TabItems (the ViewModel). When you need to change the current tab set the SelectedItem property to the correct TabItem in the ObservableCollection.